# Mocking method FieldByName in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, mocking

I am developing a class and trying to mock a dataset (TTable) included in it.

After having craeted the interface for the dataset, I started developing the mock of the method FieldByname:

```
type
  IDataSet = interface
  ...
    function FieldByName(const Name: string): TField;
  ...
  end;

  TMockDataSet = class(TInterfacedObject, IDataSet)
    ...
    function FieldByName(const Name: string): TField;
    ...
  end;
```

I tried the following implementation but it gives me a runtime error.

```
 function TMockDataSet.FieldByName(const Name: string): TField;
  var
    f: TCurrencyField;
  begin
    f := TCurrencyField.Create(nil);
    f.AsCurrency := 1; // runtime error
    result := f;
  end;
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this ?

Comment: In your case you have the problem of a mock (the dataset one) returning a mock (the field one). Try to mock the whole operation (you are doing something with the field you are getting back, right?)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here? You need an implemented `TDataSet` to associate your `TField` with, before you can assign a value to it: `f.DataSet` and `f.FieldName` should be valid. also when you have a "runtime error", please provide the exact details.

Comment: That said, a `TDataSet.FieldByName` method should be used to retrieve an *existing* field information given its name (not creating a new one)

Comment: @DelphiCoder:  Please stop editing old answers in such trivial ways.